# Bible hermeneutics migration to christianity?

Tags: discussion, migration

Shouldn't https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ be migrated to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: They are not the same thing. You should read the FAQs of each site to see what they are about.

Comment: You do realize that there's also a bible in Judaism, right?

Comment: Yes, but if I'm not mistaken that at least in my language isn't called the bible but the torah. Anyway juergen d's answer made me change my thoughts.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_hermeneutics

Comment: The best place to ask, of course, is Biblical Hermeneutics' [meta site](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/227/68 "Short answer: over my dead body.").

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the FAQs:

> Biblical Hermeneutics—Stack Exchange is for anyone who wants to know what a Biblical text means (exegesis) using the techniques or rules of interpretation (hermeneutics).
>
> We welcome Jewish, Christian, Atheist and other viewpoints as long as they take seriously the process of understanding the Biblical texts.

So, this site is about the *text* of the bible as a work of literature and its study.

---

> Christianity - Stack Exchange is for committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more. You may ask questions about any area of Christianity. Your own beliefs do not not preclude you from asking questions, but all questions must be directly related to Christianity.
>
> You've come to the right place if you have questions about:
>
> - specific doctrines or doctrinal traditions (Catholicism, Young Earth Creationism, Calvinism, etc.)
> - understanding the Bible from the perspective of a specific viewpoint (like those listed above)
> - the history of Christianity

So, this site is about the Christian religion.

---

As you can see, the scopes and audiences of these sites are different, in the same way that [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) are.

Comment: I would point out that there are discussions on the meta site for hermeneutics as to whether this is actually working as designed. That, and not this, is the place to discuss it.

Comment: @Rosinante - Whether hermeneutics is working as intended is indeed something for the hermeneutics meta. I believe the question here is simply a misunderstanding of the difference between it and the Christianity SE.

Comment: I'm all in favor of your answer, just trying to amplify it by deflecting the doctrinal tangent over there.

Answer (score 8):

Oded's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161735/1438) covers the question you *did* ask.  But I'd like to answer the question that you *didn't* ask (but I wish you had).

The Bible is Western civilization's [most influential text](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/10465/3252) and it belongs, in a sense, to all of us.  Many universities have departments dedicated to analyzing the ancient books that have been canonized by Judaism and by various Christian denominations.  To judge by the popularity of books written about discoveries related to Biblical studies, people of all religious affiliations are fascinated with the Tanakh and the New Testament.  Not all of these people would be comfortable on Christianity.SE or on Mi Yodeya.  Biblical Hermeneutics is the place on Stack Exchange for people of all stripes to ask and answer questions about the Hebrew and Greek Biblical texts.

While many of our users *are* Christian (and that includes myself), others are Jewish.  Some of our contributors are solidly orthodox (within their own religion), others have views that are not strongly influenced by any particular doctrine.  Recently, we've been evaluating the ways our community sustains divergent hermeneutical approaches while retaining well-argued, scholarly answers to Biblical questions.  One of the epiphanies we've arrived at is that our community is held together by our shared respect our common texts.

If you are also interested in exploring the text which grounds Judaism, Christianity, and Western culture in general, I encourage you to visit [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).